# How to revert back the changes in tortoise svn after commit fails?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn

I am facing one strange issue.

I have updated the project using tortoise svn and then tried to commit the project.
I got the following error while committing the project.

```
Commit failed (details follow):
File or directory 'PCUI with HUB and
 CENTRAL/PlutusHSMApplication/LoginPage.aspx.cs' is out of date; try updating
resource out of date; try updating
```

So I resolved the conflicts and then committed the project.
But all my changes are gone in this project. I am not able to find out my changes.
I can't find out any solution for this problem. the only option I have that I need to write the whole code once again.Please help me if is there any solution to solve this problem.

Comment: If I can restore the changes from visual studio then also It could help me. I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: The error message "out of date" is really not about conflicts. It merely says that you are not up to date on your local working copy compared to what is there in the repository. It is when you do an update you may encounter an actual conflict and need to resolve it accordingly. If the files that are updated in the repository, if any, are not the same as the files as you have done your changes in, you should be able to commit your changes straight away. Not sure this helps your problem though.